# Error after running shutdown os.system python

Tags: python, os.system, speaker

(First, I'm sorry for my bad english)

I was just running this code on my jupyter notebook :

```
import os
os.system('shutdown /s /t 1')
```

After I turned on my pc again then appear a strange sound came from my spekaker that i can't stop. The sound will only stop when I mute the speaker. I've tried to restart my pc and reable my speaker device on control panel. What happens with my computer? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem very python specific. If this is internal speaker, I'd try to disable and re-enable the sound driver. If it's external, try if it happens with other devices you connect it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Desktop speakers then try to disconnect them and again connect it and reinstall the sound drivers again.

if you are using laptop uninstall and reinstall sound drivers.